# OpenCL HelloWorld OSX Linker Error

Tags: macos, osx-lion, opencl, osx-mountain-lion, linker-errors

I tried to build the HelloWorld OpenCL example from the OpenCL Mac Programming Guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/OpenCL_MacProgGuide.pdf

through Xcode 4.6 on an iMac (Late 2012, OSX 10.8.3) and on my MacBook (Early 2008, OSX 10.7.5) and I'm getting what seems to be linking errors:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iih87g0495qn4c6/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-04%20at%203.35.55%20PM.png (I tried copy-pasting but the formatting looks horrendous.)

I followed all the instructions in OpenCL Mac Programming Guide, dated 2012-07-23, but no cigar.

```
// mykernel.cl

kernel void square(global float* input, global float* output) {
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    output[i] = input[i] * input[i];
}


//  main.c
//  HelloWorld

#include <stdio.h>
#include <OpenCL/OpenCL.h>
#include "mykernel.cl.h"

static void print_device_info(cl_device_id device) {
    char name[128];
    char vendor[128];

    clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_NAME, 128, name, NULL);
    clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_VENDOR, 128, vendor, NULL);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s : %s\n", vendor, name);

}
```

However, the older, longer version of the OpenCL HelloWorld from Apple, works correctly:

```
//
// File:       hello.c
//
// Abstract:   A simple "Hello World" compute example showing basic usage of OpenCL which
//             calculates the mathematical square (X[i] = pow(X[i],2)) for a buffer of
//             floating point values.
//             
//
// Version:    <1.0>
//
// Disclaimer: IMPORTANT:  This Apple software is supplied to you by Apple Inc. ("Apple")
//             in consideration of your agreement to the following terms, and your use,
//             installation, modification or redistribution of this Apple software
//             constitutes acceptance of these terms.  If you do not agree with these
//             terms, please do not use, install, modify or redistribute this Apple
//             software.
//
//             In consideration of your agreement to abide by the following terms, and
//             subject to these terms, Apple grants you a personal, non - exclusive
//             license, under Apple's copyrights in this original Apple software ( the
//             "Apple Software" ), to use, reproduce, modify and redistribute the Apple
//             Software, with or without modifications, in source and / or binary forms;
//             provided that if you redistribute the Apple Software in its entirety and
//             without modifications, you must retain this notice and the following text
//             and disclaimers in all such redistributions of the Apple Software. Neither
//             the name, trademarks, service marks or logos of Apple Inc. may be used to
//             endorse or promote products derived from the Apple Software without specific
//             prior written permission from Apple.  Except as expressly stated in this
//             notice, no other rights or licenses, express or implied, are granted by
//             Apple herein, including but not limited to any patent rights that may be
//             infringed by your derivative works or by other works in which the Apple
//             Software may be incorporated.
//
//             The Apple Software is provided by Apple on an "AS IS" basis.  APPLE MAKES NO
//             WARRANTIES, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION THE IMPLIED
//             WARRANTIES OF NON - INFRINGEMENT, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A
//             PARTICULAR PURPOSE, REGARDING THE APPLE SOFTWARE OR ITS USE AND OPERATION
//             ALONE OR IN COMBINATION WITH YOUR PRODUCTS.
//
//             IN NO EVENT SHALL APPLE BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL OR
//             CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES ( INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
//             SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
//             INTERRUPTION ) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE, REPRODUCTION, MODIFICATION
//             AND / OR DISTRIBUTION OF THE APPLE SOFTWARE, HOWEVER CAUSED AND WHETHER
//             UNDER THEORY OF CONTRACT, TORT ( INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE ), STRICT LIABILITY OR
//             OTHERWISE, EVEN IF APPLE HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
//
// Copyright ( C ) 2008 Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.
//

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Use a static data size for simplicity
//
#define DATA_SIZE (1024)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Simple compute kernel which computes the square of an input array 
//
const char *KernelSource = "\n" \
"__kernel void square(                                                       \n" \
"   __global float* input,                                              \n" \
"   __global float* output,                                             \n" \
"   const unsigned int count)                                           \n" \
"{                                                                      \n" \
"   int i = get_global_id(0);                                           \n" \
"   if(i < count)                                                       \n" \
"       output[i] = input[i] * input[i];                                \n" \
"}                                                                      \n" \
"\n";

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int err;                            // error code returned from api calls

    float data[DATA_SIZE];              // original data set given to device
    float results[DATA_SIZE];           // results returned from device
    unsigned int correct;               // number of correct results returned

    size_t global;                      // global domain size for our calculation
    size_t local;                       // local domain size for our calculation

    cl_device_id device_id;             // compute device id 
    cl_context context;                 // compute context
    cl_command_queue commands;          // compute command queue
    cl_program program;                 // compute program
    cl_kernel kernel;                   // compute kernel

    cl_mem input;                       // device memory used for the input array
    cl_mem output;                      // device memory used for the output array

    // Fill our data set with random float values
    //
    int i = 0;
    unsigned int count = DATA_SIZE;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        data[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;

    // Connect to a compute device
    //
    int gpu = 1;
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, gpu ? CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create a device group!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Create a compute context 
    //
    context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);
    if (!context)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create a compute context!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Create a command commands
    //
    commands = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &err);
    if (!commands)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create a command commands!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Create the compute program from the source buffer
    //
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) & KernelSource, NULL, &err);
    if (!program)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create compute program!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Build the program executable
    //
    err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        size_t len;
        char buffer[2048];

        printf("Error: Failed to build program executable!\n");
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, &len);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create the compute kernel in the program we wish to run
    //
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "square", &err);
    if (!kernel || err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create compute kernel!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create the input and output arrays in device memory for our calculation
    //
    input = clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,  sizeof(float) * count, NULL, NULL);
    output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(float) * count, NULL, NULL);
    if (!input || !output)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to allocate device memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }    

    // Write our data set into the input array in device memory 
    //
    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commands, input, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * count, data, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to write to source array!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set the arguments to our compute kernel
    //
    err = 0;
    err  = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &input);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &output);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(unsigned int), &count);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to set kernel arguments! %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Get the maximum work group size for executing the kernel on the device
    //
    err = clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(kernel, device_id, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(local), &local, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to retrieve kernel work group info! %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Execute the kernel over the entire range of our 1d input data set
    // using the maximum number of work group items for this device
    //
    global = count;
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commands, kernel, 1, NULL, &global, &local, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (err)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to execute kernel!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Wait for the command commands to get serviced before reading back results
    //
    clFinish(commands);

    // Read back the results from the device to verify the output
    //
    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer( commands, output, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * count, results, 0, NULL, NULL );  
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to read output array! %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Validate our results
    //
    correct = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(results[i] == data[i] * data[i])
            correct++;
    }

    // Print a brief summary detailing the results
    //
    printf("Computed '%d/%d' correct values!\n", correct, count);

    // Shutdown and cleanup
    //
    clReleaseMemObject(input);
    clReleaseMemObject(output);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(commands);
    clReleaseContext(context);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used OpenCL, but the linker error is saying it can't find a main() function in your program. Is your first code listing the complete program? If so, you need to add a main() function to the main.c file that calls your print_device_info() function.